# How to get python code to keep running even if error occurs

Tags: python, sockets, ip, ping

the code that i currently use

```
    from pythonping import ping
import random

while 1:
     d1 = (random.randrange(1,255))
     d2 = (random.randrange(1,255))
     d3 = (random.randrange(1,255))
     d4 = (random.randrange(1,255))
     h = f'{d1}.{d2}.{d3}.{d4}'
     ping(h, verbose=True)
```

but when an error happens(below) it ends the program how can i keep it going

> Request timed out Request timed out ....
>
> Request timed out
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\dwatn\Documents\document1.py", line 17, in 
> ping(h, verbose=True)   File "C:\Users\dwatn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pythonping_*init*_.py",
> line 78, in ping
> comm.run(match_payloads=match)   File "C:\Users\dwatn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pythonping\executor.py",
> line 335, in run
> payload_bytes_sent = self.send_ping(identifier, seq, payload)   File
> "C:\Users\dwatn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pythonping\executor.py",
> line 277, in send_ping
> self.socket.send(i.packet)   File "C:\Users\dwatn\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pythonping\network.py",
> line 56, in send
> self.socket.sendto(packet, (self.destination, 0)) OSError: [WinError 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable
> network

Comment: This can generate IPs with an invalid network part, and in this case did after a few iterations, is that what you mean?

Comment: yes is there a way to keep it running the code or somthing else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use try catch to handle exceptions.

```
from pythonping import ping
import random

while 1:
     d1 = (random.randrange(1,255))
     d2 = (random.randrange(1,255))
     d3 = (random.randrange(1,255))
     d4 = (random.randrange(1,255))
     h = f'{d1}.{d2}.{d3}.{d4}'
     try:
         ping(h, verbose=True)
     except:
         print("invalid ip")
```

Comment: that works tysm ive been working on this so long